# Convert list element in upper /lower case and then remove duplicate in python

Tags: python

I am new in python programming.Actually I was trying to convert list element in upper/lower case first and then remove duplicate via list Comprehensions. But I am getting [None, None, None] in output.Will you please let me know the issue ?
I dont want to use "set" to remove duplicate.

```
cnt = ["India","USA","canada","INDIA","usa"]
res =[]
m = [res.append(i) for i in [x.upper() for x in cnt ] if i not in res]
print(m)
```

Comment: If you have a version of python that implements ordered dictionaries (python3.7+), you can use `[*dict.fromkeys(map(str.upper, cnt))]` The reasons for the `None`s is that `append` returns None and works in-place.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a list comprehension but also manually appending to a list.  Do on e or the other, but not both.  You're getting a list full of `None` values because the list comprehension adds the result of `res.append(i)` to the final list, and the result of that call is `None` as it doesn't return a useful value.

Comment: You can use a Python `set` instead of a list to get a list of words without any duplicates.

Comment: You don't want to use "set" but you want to use list comprehensions, seems like your issue is in choosing the right tool for the job. A set (or dict) is perfect for detecting membership in a collection, using a list is pretty inefficient

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are appending to res, but you are printing m. Just print res.

```
cnt = ["India","USA","canada","INDIA","usa"]
res =[]
m = [res.append(i) for i in [x.upper() for x in cnt ] if i not in res]
print(res)
```

Or you can use a set.

```
cnt = ["India","USA","canada","INDIA","usa"]
resu = list({i.upper() for i in cnt}) # upper
resl = list({i.lower() for i in cnt}) # lower
print(resu, resl)
```

Comment: Thanks ppwater for pointing my mistake. Yes res is already giving me the desired output.

Comment: I don't like this syntax at all.  I think this abuses the idea of a list comprehension.  You're using a list comprehension only as a loop...you're ignoring the list that the comprehension creates, which is the whole point of a list comprehension.  It may fit on one line, but it's unexpected, and therefore confusing. - This is just my opinion.  Others may differ in theirs regarding this use of a comprehension. - Or maybe you're just showing how the OP can make the smallest change to their own code to get the result.  That's valid.  Maybe you should mention your reasoning for this answer?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to use a `set` to collect words while avoiding duplicates:

```
cnt = ["India","USA","canada","INDIA","usa"]
res = list({x.upper() for x in cnt})
print(res)
```

Result:

```
['USA', 'INDIA', 'CANADA']
```

A `set` is built up, and then is converted to a list as the last step. The use of curly braces denotes a `set` comprehension.

UPDATE: If you don't want to use a set, then I'd suggest doing something similar to what your code is doing...just use a regular loop instead of a comprehension.  I don't think it's right to use a comprehension but then not make use of the list it builds.

Here's how to get the same result using a simple loop:

```
cnt = ["India","USA","canada","INDIA","usa"]
res = []
for word in cnt:
    word = word.upper()
    if word not in res:
        res.append(word)

print(res)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Steve prompt response. Actually, I wanted to see how to archive desired output without using set.